# Analytic region of $f(z)^{1/n}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Provided that f(z) is analytic, determine the region in which the complex function $f(z)^{1/n}$ is **NOT** analytic.
A: consider the principal branch
B: consider all branches

I worked out this question for $\ln(f(z))$. However in this case I don't know where to start?

In fact I know the answer: it is on the roots of f(z) and and points on the branch

Comment: This depends, of course, on the function $f$. If $f(z)=|z|$, then $f(z)^{1/n}$ is *nowehere* analytic. If $f(z)=0$, then $f(z)^{1/n}$ is *everywhere* analytic. Perhaps, you have unstated assumptions on $f$?

Comment: I'm looking for conditions on Real and Imaginary parts of f(z) so the non-analytic region could be derived

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: @mark Ah, you are right, f(z) is analytic